# android imageview come from over screen

Tags: java, android, animation

[image]

[image]

hi.
I have a problem with android layout.
gif is what designer want I make. and I made things successfully but menu.
png(alpha image) is our menu image. last 40px of height is want to display.
and if user touch that 40px of image is coming down just like gif image shows.
I don't have any idea how can make that. Constraint Layout doesn't support negative value.

ps. png is based on 1080 height resolution. but I will add dynamic resolution calcaulator function, so don't mind about 40px. 40 just mean 'want to display part of imageview'

Comment: Please edit your question to include relevant pieces of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED.

make imageview in constraint layout xml and inflate it.
then you can set x,y location programmatically.
I confused it. because when I tried it, It doesn't work. you must know view has relative location.